# Buffer around suburb lines

Tags: qgis, buffer, boundaries

I am using QGIS 3.6.3 and I am an amateur QGIS user.

My QGIS project currently has a map outlining suburb boundaries in New South Wales, Australia. I am wondering if I can create a buffer around particular suburb boundaries? If yes, how would I go about this?

Comment: What data do you have? What have you tried? Have you had a look at the [official QGIS training manual](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/de/docs/training_manual/)? If so, which questions are left open?

Comment: Select particular suburb boundaries > create buffers for selected only. More details in [10. Vector Spatial Analysis (Buffers)](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/vector_spatial_analysis_buffers.html#vector-spatial-analysis-buffers)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.